# Azure DevOps - The system cannot find the path specified (YAML Script)

Tags: cmd, azure-devops

I am running a simple YAML script in Azure Devops to run a command line batch script. The script calls a powershell script that converts ctest outputs to junit formatting for publishing test results through Azure Devops. When I run the build pipeline, the task fails with the following error:

> 'build\collect_results.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

My first hunch is it has something to do with placing the script in the same folder as the **.vsts.yml** file, since the script before it in the pipeline works with the call to the **windows_c.cmd** in the folder *jenkins*:

```
call jenkins\windows_c.cmd
```

Has anyone else seen this error? What is the root cause of it? Is it simply a bug in Azure DevOps?